# PHP: Converting string into json array

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I need to convert this string

```
$json_string = [{"insert":"Test11"},{"insert":"","attributes":{"heading":3}}];
```

Into this json array

```
{
 "ops": 
   [{"insert":"Test11"},{"insert":"","attributes":{"heading":3}}]
}
```

I converted the original string into array like this

```
$array = json_decode($json_string);
```

Now how to create a json object named "ops" that contains this array to be parsed using delta parser https://github.com/nadar/quill-delta-parser?

Comment: `$json_obj = new array();` `$json_obj['ops'] = $array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make named index array and encode again like this:

```
   $json_string =' [{"insert":"Test11"},{"insert":"","attributes":{"heading":3}}]';
    $array = json_decode($json_string);
    $array['ops'] = $array;
    echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could decode it, wrap it in an array with a key `"ops"` and encode it again

```
$json_string = json_encode(["ops" => json_decode($json_string, true)]);
echo $json_string;
```

Output

```
{"ops":[{"insert":"Test11"},{"insert":"","attributes":{"heading":3}}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works too using [type casting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) as shorthand:

```
(object)['ops'=>'[{"insert":"Test11"},{"insert":"","attributes":{"heading":3}}]']

/* Output
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["ops"]=>
  string(50) "[{insert:Test11},{insert:,attributes:{heading:3}}]"
} */
```

It's efficient, easy to keep in mind, easy to read and this can save using intermediary variables.